# Setting up MDM Server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm, csr

I have an own application which runs on a Web Server. I want to use the server as an MDM server so that I can remotely push my mobile application to user's mobile devices and control my mobile application on the user's device remotely.

After googling, I found out this concept was called MDM. I did not find a solution to remotely install my Android application though. But for iOS application, I found out a way.

The Apple Push Certificate Portal can be used for this. It says Upload CSR signed by third party vendor. I don't understand who the third party vendor is.
I have an SSL certificate for my application running on the web server. I uploaded the CSR generated to get the SSL certificate to the Apple's Push Certificate Portal but it says Invalid.

So, can you please help me understand the process to configure an MDM server and controll my mobile applications on the user's devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Enterprise account with the Apple to do that.
Refer

1. [Sample iOS server](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)
2. [MDM](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/1-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH1-SW1)